# Alternatives to carbonates?

Tags: aqueous-solution, food-chemistry

This isn't strictly 'pure' chemistry but the knowledge to answer it is probably much closer to chemistry than any other subject.

The question is a simple one - are there any other non-toxic aqueous acids that could substitute for carbonic acid ($\ce{CO2}$ dissolved  in water), that could substitute for carbonates as a basis for an experience similar to soda drinks? I'm thinking of chemical suitability rather than economics. Maybe other weak or organic acids? Or non acids even?

Comment: If you're talking about $\ce{CO2}$ in the context of beverage carbonation, you may want to read about $\ce{N2}$ being used in [some beers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guinness).

Comment: It's not just mild acidity that gives club soda/seltzer/tonic... its taste, but the bubbles, as well. Citric acid is often used in foods, including powdered fruit-flavored drinks, but it doesn't give the tingly, bubbly sensation of soda. As Cole Porter stated, "I get no kick from champagne" without CO2. C'est la vie.